# Technical differences between workstation and normal video cards for a creator?

Tags: video, graphics-card, gpu

I happen to be a designer. I will be using Photoshop and Illustrator. The newer versions (CC 2020) give me some lag on my APU. So I was thinking of going for a video card. I also occasionally need some video work, so Premiere and AfterEffects (older versions) too. Now, as I was looking for these things, I stumbled upon the usual suspects - Nvidia and AMD's latest series (30 and 6000). But there are availability issues where I live as these are used too much for mining and gaming. I also happened to read something about "creator" cards or workstation cards like the Titan, which are frankly out of budget. I have shortlisted a few. Can someone help me tell apart the differences between a typical GPU like the AMD RX 580, 5700 XT or Nvidia 2080 Ti and a workstation GPU like AMD Radeon Pro or older Nvidia Quadro cards? I might be able to get these easily locally, but I need to know what's the difference exactly?

Comment: The graphic cards that Adobe products hardware acceleration support are listed with the applicable support article.  Do you have one of those cards?  You should only get one of those cards otherwise Adobe will not allow you to use them with hardware acceleration

Answer (score 1):

Usually, workstation cards like the Titan have a bigger VRAM. Bigger VRAMs specifically help game developers store larger texture files, but at the same time, also allow better video work. For Illustrator and Photoshop I'm afraid this distinction means nothing. Any modern video card with at least 6 (recommended 8) GB of VRAM will suffice. The RX 580 you're talking about is actually a great option.

APUs are also great I'm not sure why you're getting lag. Maybe the version has bad optimization? Has happened with me and I won't rule it out. Test your APU with other versions first. Also remember the system RAM, allocated space for scratch disks, monitor resolution, HDD/SSD quality, and finally the processor also need to be factored in. In the case of your APU the problem might be the cores/threads count (eg. first gen AMD APUs are not that great for handling modern apps), and not the integrated Radeon graphics. Same goes with Intel processors.

If you're looking for the differences between the video cards I recommend the guide on types of video cards on Spearblade: [Types of GPU](https://spearblade.com/general-gaming/types-of-gpus/). The latest Titan on the other hand is more geared towards machine learning and AI than graphic design and video editing IMO. Check the official page, always, before you make up your mind: [Titan V](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/titan/titan-v/).